# que hacer cuando varias routes se repitan ruby on rails 5

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, ruby

lo que pasa es que quiero codificar código apenas comienzo en este rol quiero programar bien es para un JavaScript y tambien lo llama desde controler los metodos select_region, select_ciudad ,select_planta se repiten en otros modelos

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  resources :eventos do
   collection do
     get :autocomplete_centro_costo_fullname
     get :select_region
     get :select_ciudad
     get :select_planta
     get :select_producto
  end
end

post 'eventos/calcular_precio', to: 'eventos#calcular_precio'
resources :reunionesvalores
resources :reuniones do
  collection do
    get :autocomplete_centro_costo_fullname
    get :select_region
    get :select_ciudad
    get :select_planta
    get :select_producto
  end
end

post 'reuniones/calcular_precio', to: 'reuniones#calcular_precio'
post 'reuniones/calcular_presupuesto', to: 'reuniones#calcular_presupuesto'

resources :centros_costos
resources :plantas
resources :ciudades
resources :regiones
resources :negocios
resources :refrigerios

resources :productos do
  get :select_region, on: :collection
  get :select_ciudad, on: :collection
  get :select_planta, on: :collection
end  


get 'static_pages/home'

get 'static_pages/help'
root :to => 'refrigerios#index'

end
```

application.js

```
  $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){


    // Empieza codigo para select anidados
    $("#negocio").change(function(event, data) {
    var id_negocio = $('select#negocio :selected').val();
    $.ajax({
    url: '/productos/select_region',
    dataType: "JSON",
    type: 'GET',
    data: { idnegocio: id_negocio },
    success: function(data) {
        var $select = $('#region');
        $select.empty().append('<option value="">Seleccione Region</option>');
        $(data).each(function (index, o) {    
        var $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.id).text(o.nombre);
        $select.append($option);
    });      
   }
   });
   // inicializar los selects
   var $select = $('#producto_planta_id');
     $select.empty().append('<option value="">Seleccione ciudad</option>');

   });

   $("#region").change(function(event, data) {
   var id_region =  $('select#region :selected').val();
   $.ajax({
   url: '/productos/select_ciudad',
   dataType: "JSON",
   type: 'GET',
   data: { idregion: id_region },
   success: function(data) {
      var $select = $('#ciudad');
      $select.empty().append('<option value="">Seleccione una ciudad</option>');
      $(data).each(function (index, o) {    
      var $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.id).text(o.nombre);
      $select.append($option);
        });      
    }
   });

 });

 $("#ciudad").change(function(event, data) {
  var id_ciudad =  $('select#ciudad :selected').val();
  $.ajax({
  url: '/productos/select_planta',
  dataType: "JSON",
  type: 'GET',
  data: { idciudad: id_ciudad },
  success: function(data) {
    var $select = $('#producto_planta_id');
    $select.empty().append('<option value="">Seleccione la planta</option>');
    $(data).each(function (index, o) {    
    var $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.id).text(o.nombre);
    $select.append($option);
    });      
}
});

});
 // Termina codigo para select anidado
```

});

```
class ProductosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_producto, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /productos
  # GET /productos.json
  def index
    @negocios = Negocio.all
    @q = Producto.ransack(params[:q])
    @productos = @q.result(distinct: true).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
  end

  def select_region
    rs = Region.where(:negocio_id => params[:idnegocio]).order('nombre').all
    respond_to do |format|
     format.json {render json: rs } 
     format.html
    end
  end

  def select_ciudad
    rs = Ciudad.where(:region_id => params[:idregion]).order('nombre').all
    respond_to do |format|
     format.json {render json: rs }
     format.html
    end
  end

  def select_planta
    rs = Planta.where(:ciudad_id => params[:idciudad]).order('nombre').all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {render json: rs }
      format.html
    end
  end

  # GET /productos/1
  # GET /productos/1.json

  def show
  end

  # GET /productos/new

  def new
    @producto = Producto.new
    @negocios = Negocio.all
  end

  # GET /productos/1/edit

  def edit
    @negocios = Negocio.all
  end

  # POST /productos
  # POST /productos.json

  def create
    @producto = Producto.new(producto_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @producto.save
        format.html { redirect_to @producto, notice: 'El Producto fue creado correctamente.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @producto }
      else
        @negocios = Negocio.all
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @producto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /productos/1
  # PATCH/PUT /productos/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @producto.update(producto_params)
         format.html { redirect_to @producto, notice: 'El Producto actualizado correctamente.' }
         format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @producto }
      else
        @negocios = Negocio.all
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @producto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /productos/1
  # DELETE /productos/1.json
  def destroy
   @producto.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to productos_url, notice: 'El Producto fue destruido con éxito.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
   end


  private
   # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_producto
    @producto = Producto.find(params[:id])
  end

     #  Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def producto_params
      params.require(:producto).permit(:nombre, :precio, :refrigerio_id,
      :fullnombre, :planta_id,:buscaprodufullnombre)
  end
end
```

formulario

```
 <%= simple_form_for(@producto) do |f| %>
 <%= f.error_notification %>
 <br>
  <div class="form-inputs">

   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
       <%= f.input :nombre ,label: "1.Nombre del producto",
  placeholder: "Ingrese el nombre del producto",input_html: { title: 'Nombre del producto' }%>
     </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
     <%= f.input :precio ,label: "2.Precio",
  placeholder: "Ingrese el precio del producto",input_html: { title: 'Precio del producto' }%>
     </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-4 col-md-4">
     <%= f.association :refrigerio ,label: "3.Tipo de refrigerio" , class: "form-control", 
      prompt:"Seleccione el tipo de refrigerio",input_html: { title: 'Tipo de refrigerio' }%>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
   <div class=" col-xs-12  col-sm-4 col-md-4 ">
     <label>4.Negocio</label>
     <%= select_tag "negocio", options_from_collection_for_select(@negocios, "id", "nombre"),
    class: "form-control", :include_blank => "Seleccione el Negocio"   %>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
 </div>
 <br>
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <label>5.Region</label>
   <%= select_tag "region", "<option value="">Seleccione la region</option>".html_safe, class: "form-control" %>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
 </div>
 <br>
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
          <label>6.Ciudad</label>
     <%= select_tag "ciudad", "<option value="">Seleccione la ciudad</option>".html_safe, class: "form-control" %>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
 </div>
 <br>
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
          <label>7.Planta</label>
     <%= select_tag "producto[planta_id]","<option value="">Seleccione una de las planta</option>".html_safe, class: "form-control" %>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit %>
 </div>  

 </div>
```

Comment: Las rutas se pueden repetir sin problema siempre que estén dentro de un _namespace_ tal como lo estás haciendo en tus rutas actualmente. ¿Cuál es tu duda?, ¿estás obteniendo algún error?

Comment: Solo muestras la lógica de productos, pero si es exactamente la misma lógica de tus selects en todos tus controlador, quizás sea mejor dejarlos en un controlador aparte en vez de replicar la misma lógica en cada controlador donde vayas a realizar la consulta. Lo otro podría ser usar un concern de controlador que guarde esa lógica, pero todo depende de lo que requieras